# Path to local file in a cordova app, Meteor 1.3

Tags: cordova, meteor

Using Meteor 1.3 to build a cordova app. In which directory should I put local asset files, an image for example, that should go in the bundle? How do I get the url that references them?

Comment: Simplest way is to put them in the meteor project's /public folder. They are bundled up along with the app anyway once its built and run on the device. Even icons and splash screens put in the public folder somehow are bundled up to the resource folder of the app.